# How to enforce line breaks in single line if statements using allman brace style

Tags: typescript, tslint

How can I configure tslint to enforce this

```
if ( test )
{
    return true;
}
```

instead of this:

```
if ( test ) { return true; }
```

My tslint file looks like this:

```
"one-line": [
    false,
    "check-catch",
    "check-finally",
    "check-else",
    "check-open-brace",
    "check-whitespace"
]

"brace-style": [
    "allman",
    {
        "allowSingleLine": false
    }
]
```

But that doesn't work. Thanks in advance!